# Differentiation of matrix with respect to vector

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vectors

I have two row vectors $y$ and $k$ of size $1 \times m$ and $1 \times p$ respectively, a matrix $X$ of size $p \times m$. What is the differentiation of:
                 $$(y - kX)^{T} (y - kX)$$ with respect to $k$.

Is it $-2yX^{T} +2k(XX^{T})$?

Also can anyone suggest a good material for understanding matrix differentiation - with respect to vector and matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $w=(kX-y),\,$ then you can write the function, differential, and gradient as
$$\eqalign{
 f &= w^Tw = {\rm tr}(w^Tw) {\,\dot =\,} w:w \cr
df &= 2w:dw = 2w:dk\,X = 2wX^T:dk \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial k} &= 2wX^T = 2(kX-y)X^T \cr
}$$
So it appears that your hypothesis is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Set $f(k) = (y - kX)^{T} (y - kX).$ Then, if we drop terms not linear in $dk,$
$$\begin{align}
f'(k)(dk) & :=
f(k+dk) - f(k) \\
&= - y^{T}(dk)X - X^{T}(dk)^{T}y + X^{T}(dk)^{T}kX + X^{T}k^{T}(dk)X \\
\end{align}$$

As you can see $dk$ occurs in the middle of the terms. That makes it difficult, to not say impossible, to write the derivative without including $dk$ or some other placeholder.